# Find certain data with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have a file in the following format:

```
someinformation="someNumbers"-result
```

My code is:

```
re.findall('someinformation="(.*?)"-result', str(data))
```

Given the example:

```
test1="3"-result
```

I want to get `3`, but my code doesn't find anything.

```
re.findall('test1=(.*?)-result', str(data))
```

works, but returns `"3"` and not `3`. What I find strange is that the following:

```
  re.findall('test1="3"-result', str(data))
```

doesn't find anything either.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in following code :

```
re.findall('test1="3"-result'), str(data))
```

Just remove the extra parenthesis and see the result,also note that if you defined your string like following you won't need to use `str` function at all :

```
>>> data='test1="3"-result'
>>> re.findall('test1="3"-result', data)
['test1="3"-result']
```

Comment: sry, my mistake, the code om my side is correct, i posted it wrong, however my problem remains

Comment: @mat Did you have defined your string like mine? why use used `str`?

Comment: this might be the problem, data is a list of strings, and by casting it to a string i thought i could combine the strings, but this might have been a mistake. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: @mat Indeed, converting the a list to string with `str` will include the brackets too, can you add the data to your question?

Comment: The data is basicly as indicated in my first "code" line, severeal lines of data, where i want to read the number from each line. The data variable is the result of a nother regex call which extracts all the lines containing the results.